# Table with 2 dates I want a single list of unique dates

Tags: sql, select

Say for example I have a table with date start and date end

```
Item 1 10/2/2019 12/2/2019
Item 2 10/2/2019 15/2/2019.
```

I wish to have a result of

```
Item 1 10/2/2019
Item 2 12/2/2019
Item 3 15/2/2019
```

In a single column that I can use for further queries

Can’t think of how to get the desired result

See above

Comment: Your sample data is incomplete... Your "table data" shows 2 items, but your "results" show 3 items. Also, why do you expect your `Item 2` resulting date to be `12/2/2019`? Please explain the logic behind your question...

Comment: Where does the `Item 3` in the results come from? Shouldn't it be `Item 2` instead?

Comment: Also if there are several records in the result with the same date, which one do you want to keep?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you asked for if you are using Oracle:

```
select 'Item ' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        ORDER BY date_row
    ) row_num
    , date_row 
from (
select start_date as Date_row from table1
union
select end_date as Date_row from table1);
```

And here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cba9ab70357977e9dc3b92a78e74bd5e)

Here is what you asked for if you are using MySQL:

```
select concat("Item ", ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_row)) as Item
       ,  date_row 
from (
   select start_date as Date_row from table1 as t1 
   union
   select end_date as Date_row from table1 as t2
) as test;
```

And here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=482aad1f33b928c38da850b228f471a6)

Here is what you asked for if you are using Postgres:

```
select 'Item ' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        ORDER BY date_row
    ) row_num
    , date_row 
from (
select start_date as Date_row from table1 as t1
union
select end_date as Date_row from table1 as t2) as t3;
```

And here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=57a36affc7b8b645c3d7c70f88ab2333)

Comment: How did you know it was oracle?

Comment: @CaiusJard I did not, it was just an example. I do agree that OP should always state what DB is he using. I have added some more examples....

Answer (score 1):

Probably this:

```
SELECT 'startdate' as datekind, startdate 
FROM table
UNION
SELECT 'enddate', enddate 
FROM table
```

The kind is optional but I added it in to demo how you would retain knowledge of whether  a date was start or end. You can add other columns like ID in in the same way

If you don't want to squish duplicates add the word ALL after UNION

NOTE - the presence of the kind column will influence whether a date is deemed a duplicate of another row or not. This query can still produce repeated dates if one is a start and the other an end. If this is unacceptable, remove the dateline column (and accept that you won't know what they are)

If we're generating a unique list of dates and the lowest item associated:

```
SELECT x.d, min(x.item) as i 
FROM(
  SELECT startdate as d, item FROM table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT enddate, item FROM table
) x
GROUP BY x.d
```